# PIG - How to sequentially call multiple store commands

Tags: multithreading, hadoop, apache-pig

I implemented some logic into my own store function TestStorage. Now, I want to call this store function multiple times in my PIG script and require that the store operations are processed sequentially(!).

An example:

```
STORE rows INTO 'dummy'
USING TestStorage;


STORE rows INTO 'dummy2'
USING TestStorage;
```

I figured that PIG is actually starting two threads for each store operation. Leading to the following order of operations:

```
Init TestStorage
Init TestStorage
Finished TestStorage
Finished TestStorage
```

I found a way that works if I run the PIG script in local mode. By simply using a ReentrentLock in my TestStorage class I can stop one of the threads until the other has finished iterating through all tuples giving me the following order of operations:

```
Init TestStorage
Finished TestStorage
Init TestStorage
Finished TestStorage
```

However, beside the fact that the above solution is not very nice, it does not work on our Hadoop cluster :-( On our live system, both threads still work in parallel. 
Maybe this has something to do with the fact that the store function is running within a reducer task.

**Update:**
I found out that within a reducer task PIG iterates through the input data in the HDFS and for each tuple sends this tuple to the first and then to the second storage instances. Consequently, both store operations will work in parallel :-(

Any idea how to circumvent this problem? Is there, for a example, a way to use file in the HDFs a as input for a second store operation?

Thanks in advance!
Sebastian

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do this?
I dont see any out-of-the-box way to do this. If you are duplicating the same file in another location, I would recommend writing a wrapper shell script which would do that - so shell script will run your pig script which creates 1 file, and then copies the output from pig script to new location.

Comment: I am using PIG to learn a machine learning model. In the first steps, I create my feature matrix. The store function contains the actual logic for learning the model. Ideally, the model should run multiple times over the learning data. Hence, I would like PIG to iterate twice or multiple times over the feature matrix. Maybe you are right. Copying the feature matrix file to a different location might work, but I always hoped that PIG would support me doing this :-(